# Sqlite: Select last row group by 2 column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get the last row of my table but with 2 column.

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id1| id2 | info    |
+----+-----+---------+
|  1 | 2   | info    |
|  2 | 1   | NULL    |
|  2 | 3   | info    |
|  2 | 1   | NULL    |
+----+-----+---------+
```

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id1
```

but I got:

```
1     2
2     3
2     1
```

What I need:

```
2     3
2     1
```

In other words, I need the last row of each couple ids
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1, id2 FROM table WHERE id1=2
```

This should do the trick. Unless you want to apply an aggregation function to other columns, [`SELECT DISTINCT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#distinct) should to the trick. It will drop any duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all items with the highest value dynamically, you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id1, id2 FROM table WHERE id1=(SELECT MAX(id1))
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL.